# String helper functions in NASM Win16 Assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

**Environment**

[NASM](https://nasm.us/) is required to build this program, and [DosBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) is required to run it. I'd recommend installing these using the [Scoop Package Manager](https://scoop.sh/). Feel free to ignore install statements for any programs you have installed already.

> ```
> iwr -useb get.scoop.sh | iex
> scoop install git
> scoop install dosbox
> scoop install nasm
> ```

**Building**

> ```
> nasm -f bin -o helper.com helper.asm
> ```

**Running**

Load DosBox, then mount the path where `helper.com` resides to any available drive. For those unfamiliar, it can be any drive in the A-Z range.

```
mount H: C:\Users\T145\Desktop\
H:
dir
helper.com
```

***helper.asm***

```lisp
bits 16
org 0x100

section .text

_main:
    lea     di, [prompt]
    call    putstring

    lea     di, [string]
    call    getstring

    lea     di, [hello]
    call    putstring

    lea     di, [string]
    call    putstring

    mov     ah, 0x4c     ; standard exit code
    mov     al, 0
    int     0x21

; no parameters
; returns a char in ax
getchar:
    mov     ah, 0        ; call interrupt x16 sub interrupt 0
    int     0x16
    mov     ah, 0
    ret

; takes a char to print in dx
; no return value
putchar:
    mov     ax, dx       ; call interrupt x10 sub interrupt xE
    mov     ah, 0x0E
    mov     cx, 1
    int     0x10
    ret

; takes an address to write to in di
; writes to address until a newline is encountered
; returns nothing
getstring:
    call    getchar      ; read a character
    cmp     ax, 13       ; dos has two ascii characters for new lines 13 then 10
    je      .done        ; its not a 13, whew...
    cmp     ax, 10       ; check for 10 now
    je      .done        ; its not a 10, whew...
    mov     [di], al     ; write the character to the current byte
    inc     di           ; move to the next address
    mov     dx, ax       ; dos doesn't print as it reads like windows, let's fix that
    call    putchar
    jmp     getstring
.done:
    mov     dx, 13       ; write a newline for sanity
    call    putchar
    mov     dx, 10
    call    putchar
    ret

; takes an address to write to in di
; writes to address until a newline is encountered
; returns nothing
putstring:
    cmp     byte [di], 0 ; see if the current byte is a null terminator
    je      .done        ; nope keep printing
.continue:
    mov     dl, [di]     ; grab the next character of the string
    mov     dh, 0        ; print it
    call    putchar
    inc     di           ; move to the next character
    jmp     putstring
.done:
    ret

section .data

    prompt: db "Please enter your first name: ", 0
    string: times 20 db 0
    hello: db "Hello, ", 0
```

***Output***

[image: output]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using BIOS interrupts instead of DOS?

Comment: @Shift_Left No, not really. Idk wym by usage of DOS over BIOS interrupts tbh. This is my first time messing around w/ 16-bit assembly. I've read through [this official documentation page](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html) on the topic, but that's about it.

Comment: This is not Win16, it is 8086 DOS.

Comment: @ecm Ty for that clarification; I'll be sure to use it in future questions relating to 16 bit NASM running on DOSBOX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the face of all else the assembler assumes a 16bit flat binary, so all that is required is;

> ~$ nasm ?.asm -o?.com

Although not wrong, but even **bits 16** is redundant. In operating system development you might **use32** or **use64** to utilize those instruction sets, but it would still be a flat binary file. Otherwise, the only thing that makes this type of executable unique is;

```
    org 0x100
```

This establishes the entry point, so a label like **main** is unnecessary unless it is required to branch back to the beginning of the application.

As to the question I asked in your original post, knowing what resources you have to deal with is monumentally important. DOS provides a lot of utility that can be found [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm), therefore this

```
    mov     dx, Prompt
    mov     ah, WRITE
    int    DOS
```

replaces all of this

```
    putstring:
        cmp     byte [di], 0 ; see if the current byte is a null terminator
        je      .done        ; nope keep printing
    .continue:
        mov     dl, [di]     ; grab the next character of the string
        mov     dh, 0        ; print it
        call    putchar
        inc     di           ; move to the next character
        jmp     putstring
    .done:
        ret
```

by terminating string with what DOS expects as so

```
    Prompt   db   13, 10, 13, 10, 'Please enter your first name: $'
```

and because CR/LF is embedded in string now, this can be eliminated.

```
    mov    dx, 13       ; write a newline for sanity
   call    putchar
   mov     dx, 10
   call    putchar
```

Input as such

```
; Read string from operator
    mov     dx, InpBuff
    mov     ah, READ
    int     DOS

; To a buffer specified with Max input of 128 chars. -1 is just a place holder
; which will be replace by the number of characters entered.

    InpBuff:  db   128, -1
```

The input is terminated with 0x0D and must be replaced with '$'. This little snippet does that.

```
; Terminate this input with '$'
    mov     bx, dx
    movzx   ax, byte [bx+1]
    inc     al
    inc     al
    add     bx, ax
    mov     byte [bx], '$'
```

replaces these

```
    ; no parameters
    ; returns a char in ax
    getchar:
        mov     ah, 0        ; call interrupt x16 sub interrupt 0
        int     0x16
        mov     ah, 0
        ret

    ; takes an address to write to in di
    ; writes to address until a newline is encountered
    ; returns nothing
    getstring:
        call    getchar      ; read a character
        cmp     ax, 13       ; dos has two ascii characters for new lines 13 then 10
        je      .done        ; its not a 13, whew...
        cmp     ax, 10       ; check for 10 now
        je      .done        ; its not a 10, whew...
        mov     [di], al     ; write the character to the current byte
        inc     di           ; move to the next address
        mov     dx, ax       ; dos doesn't print as it reads like windows, let's fix that
        call    putchar
        jmp     getstring
```

So all in all this code is almost 50% smaller (91 bytes vs 163) and only because I've utilized what DOS provides. If I was to have utilized BIOS calls, then my code would not have been that much smaller, maybe 5-10 %.

```
           org 0x100

          DOS equ   33      ; = 21H
        WRITE equ    9
         READ equ   10

        ; Display initial prompting
            mov     dx, Prompt
            mov      ah, WRITE
            int    DOS

        ; Read string from operator
            mov     dx, InpBuff
            mov     ah, READ
            int     DOS

        ; Terminate this input with '$'
            mov     bx, dx
            movzx   ax, byte [bx+1]
            inc     al
            inc     al
            add     bx, ax
            mov     byte [bx], '$'

       ; Display next prompting
            push    dx        ; We will want this pointer again
            mov     dx, hello
            mov     ah, WRITE
            int     DOS

            pop     dx
            inc     dx        ; Bump over max and actual lengths
            inc     dx
            int     DOS       
            ret

      Prompt   db   13, 10, 13, 10, 'Please enter your first name: $'
       hello   db   10, 10, 9, 'Hello, $'
     InpBuff:  db   128, -1
```

I changed the formatting of hello slightly just you can see the difference and experiment a little and replace 10's with 13's @ hello and watch what happens.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! Just out of curiosity, why do you `inc dx` twice after popping, and have `-1` on the tail of `InpBuff`? To the last point, there's no [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) code for it.

Comment: DX is pointing to the very beginning of InBuf, so it has to be incremented twice to point to the actual text. -1 is just a place holder so when I'm looking for the string or that section of the buffer in debug, it's easy to identify, otherwise it doesn't need to be there. I used inc twice has it's one byte shorter than `add dx,2`. The second byte of InBuff will be replace with the number of characters entered.

Answer (score 3):

### There's plenty to optimize here!

In NASM you get the address simply by writing `mov di, prompt`. This has a shorter encoding than `lea di, [prompt]`. (In MASM this would be `mov  di, offset prompt` giving the same benefit over the `lea` form).

Instead of writing the pair `mov ah, 0x4c` `mov al, 0`, you could combine these in 1 instruction as `mov ax, 0x4C00`. This shaves off 1 byte from the program.

Your *getchar* returns a **byte** in `AX` and your *putchar* expects a **byte** in `DX`. You would be better off if you used `AL` and `DL`. This would avoid those several `mov ah, 0` and `mov dh, 0` instructions.

Your *putchar* code uses the BIOS.Teletype function 0x0E. This function does not expect anything in the `CX` register. What it does require is that you specify the displaypage in the `BH` register. Simply add `mov bh, 0` here. And if it's even possible that your program has to run on the graphical video mode then it would make sense to write `mov bx, 0x0007` because then the color for the character is taken from the `BL` register.

I see that the *getstring* code also checks for the linefeed code 10. No one does that. If the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, you'll receive the carriage return code 13 and that's the only code that you need to check. The linefeed code only comes into play when outputting.

The pair of instructions `mov [di], al` `inc di` (3 bytes) can be replaced by the 1-byte instruction `stosb`. Given that your program is in the .COM file format we have `DS`=`ES` and the direction flag is almost certainly going to be clear. Ideal for using the string primitive assembly instructions. This also means that your *putstring* routine could use `lodsb` if you're willing to trade in `DI` for `SI` as the input parameter.

An interesting optimization comes from eliminating a *tail call*. You wrote `call putchar` directly followed by `ret`. This is equivalent to writing `jmp putchar`. Both shorter and faster this way!

### Make it better

- Your *getstring* procedure must not allow the user to input more than 19 characters. Anything more would overflow the 20-byte buffer.
- Your *getstring* procedure should store (in the buffer) a terminating zero when the finishing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key arrives. This way the buffer can be used repeatedly and not just this one time.
- In assembly we want to avoid all kinds of jumping because those are more time consuming than many other instructions.
  Your *putstring* code uses a `je` and a `jmp` instruction on each iteration of the loop. The code below only uses the `jne` instruction on each iteration.

  ```
  ; IN (di)
  putstring:
      jmp     .first
  .continue:
      call    putchar
      inc     di           ; move to the next character
  .first:
      mov     al, [di]     ; grab the next character of the string
      cmp     al, 0
      jne     .continue
      ret

  ; IN (al)
  putchar:
      mov     ah, 0x0E     ; BIOS.Teletype
      mov     bx, 0x0007
      int     0x10
      ret
  ```

  Using `DX` as the input for *putchar* is a poor choice, not only because `DL` would be enough, but especially because you need the character in `AL` anyway. So why not move it there in the first place?

### Be consistent

Always write your numbers the same way. You wrote `mov ah, 0x4c` and also `mov ah, 0x0E`.
I suggest you use capitals for the hexadecimal digits and always write as many digits as will fit in the destination. So don't write stuff like `mov ah, 0xE`.
In case you're wondering why I make this suggestion. Using uppercase hexadecimal digits enhances the contrast with the lowercase `0x` prefix or lowercase `h` suffix. Readability is very important in a program.

```
mov ah, 0x4C
mov ah, 0x0E
```

or

```
mov ah, 4Ch
mov ah, 0Eh
```

For many programmers function numbers are easiest recognized when expressed in hexadecimal.
You could thus write `mov ah, 0x00` `int 0x16` in your *getchar* routine.

---

As a final note, your labels are well chosen and the comments that you've added are all to the point. Congrats...