# Printing a string in NASM Win16 Assembly

Tags: strings, windows, assembly, nasm

A small script that simply prints a given string. It's an improved snippet that combines some recommendations given in my post on [string helper functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/232221/string-helper-functions-in-nasm-win16-assembly).

```
org 100h

mov     si, hello
call    puts
ret

puts:
    jmp     .run
.putc:
    mov     ah, 0Eh
    mov     bx, 7
    int     10h
.run:
    lodsb
    cmp     al, 0
    jne     .putc
    ret

hello db "Hello World!", 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have all the elements. The only thing that can be eliminated is **jmp .run**, as follows:

```
org 0x100

        mov     si, Prompt
        call    puts
        ret

  puts: mov     ah, 0xe
        mov     bx, 7
 .read: lodsb
        or       al, al
        jnz     .post     
        ret
 .post: int     0x10
        jmp     .read

 Prompt: db  'Hello World', 0
```

As INT 10H does not trash AH or BX, there is no need to reinitialize them each time through the loop.

Comment: Use `TEST reg, reg` to check for zero in preference to `OR reg, reg`, since the former is more likely to fuse with the conditional branch. I also find it more readable.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree, as `test` is more representative of what is being done and I think that's what you mean by more readable. Whereas `or` implies AL is being modified for some other reason.

Comment: I interpret "trashing" as having a value reset to some default value. Would this be accurate? If so, Is there a way to efficiently determine if an interrupt trashes a register? I've been using [HelpPC](http://www.stanislavs.org/helppc/idx_interrupt.html) as a reference for interrupts, and there's no mention of trashing.

Comment: I use `trashing` in the context that a register has been modified by an interrupt, function or subroutine where its value upon return is indeterminate. As to the reference your using, I think it would be safe to say that if nothing is returned, then nothing is modified either or it specifically states returned values.